# I am unable to connect my MongoDb with Vs code

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman

I used MongoDb Atlas for my progrom , But I am unable to connect with database ,
Here I used Postman to perform different operation but whenever I send some request, Error will occured.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Product = require('./modelss/product');

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://<UserName>:<Password>@cluster1.un9kapv.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
).then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to the database!')

}).catch(() => {
    console.log('Connection failed!')
});


const createProduct = async(req, res,next) => {
    const createdProduct = new Product({
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price
    });
    console.log(createdProduct);
    const result = await createProduct.save();
    res.json(result);
};

const GetProduct = async(req,res,next) => {
    const products = await Product.find().exec();
    res.json(products);
}

exports.createProduct = createProduct;
exports.GetProduct = GetProduct;
```

Before Sending any request from Postman it shows-:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUNbZ.png)

But After sending request -:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVLYG.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Try adding your IP Address to your mongoDB access panel or make it open access to all IP(only for development purposes).
2. Replace "Username" and "Password" in mongoose.connect with your actual username and password for the database which you have made.

To debug such things you can catch the error and then console.log it out-

```
catch(e){
console.log(e)
}
```